# Как правильно раскрыть и упаковать cpio архив?

Tags: linux, файлы, tar, gzip, archive

Есть некоторый файл test.gz, необходимо открыть его, изменить файл и потом обратно упаковать. Столкнулся с тем что если просто открываю и пакую файл ничего не меняя, то они не совпадают, даже банально по размеру.

```
 gunzip -c test.gz | cpio -i
```

Выдает что 114000 блоков

Далее пакую

```
find . | cpio -o -H newc | gzip -9 > "test1.gz"
cpio: File ./test.gz grew, 7639543 new bytes not copied
```

И выдает что уже 129000 блоков
При этом файл после этой операции уже перестает работать, я так понимаю там пустые какие то пустые блоки создает.
Как сделать так чтобы файл не менялся?

Comment: совершенно непонятно: а) что вы там распаковываете и б) зачем запаковываете обратно не только распакованное содержимое, но и исходный архив, и в) почему считаете, что получившийся новый архив, содержащий больше информации, не должен её содержать, а также г) при чём тут вообще программа *tar*.

Comment: tar добавил чисто из соображений схожести, распаковываю прошивку asa(ядро), пункт (в) я просто не могу понять о чем у вас речь. Если я распакую архив а потом запакую то что распаковалось, то по закону логики ничего  не должно измениться.

Comment: если вы распаковали архив из файла, а потом в другой файл запаковываете *и* содержимое *и* сам исходный файл, то размер нового файла будет явно больше размера исходного. // в общем, совершенно не ясно, в чём у вас там проблема. попытайтесь перечитать текст вопроса как бы чужими глазами, а потом переформулировать его, нажав [edit]

Comment: есть архив _u_ его распаковываем и получаем набор файлов _k_ затем запаковываем этот набор файлов _k_ обратно и получаем другой архив отличный от _u_ ???? странно

Comment: а запаковываете «набор файлов k» плюс исходный файл.

Comment: зачем? исходный то я не трогаю

Comment: я не знаю «зачем». но знаю «почему»: потому что исходный файл находится в том же каталоге и его имя попадает в выдачу команды `$ find .`

Comment: не попадает его там нет, он собирает файлы из отдельной директории, мы столько времени потратили на чтоб прийти к этому, жесть

Comment: @LOGA, в этом виновата постановка вопроса... после прочтения у меня создалось тоже впечатление, что и у alexander barkin'а...  предлагаю переформулировать проблему, озвученную в вопросе таким образом, чтобы она стала *воспроизводимой*...